# Using opendaylight to document networks

Tags: opendaylight

I am facing a task to analyze, document and visualize a rather large global network (more than 200 sites, various technologies) and wonder if opendaylight might help me with this. The documentation should mainly focus on Layer 3 and Layer 4 but may partially also include L2 topology. There is no need to actually use a controller to configure devices through southbound APIs, but I would like to use the benefits of a structured, consistent description (e.g. YANG) and a visualization ([DLUX](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_dlux:Main), [NeXt](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/NeXt:Main)) which ODL provides.

So here's my question: Is there any way to manually add a topology (nodes, links) through a graphical editor to ODL?

From the general project description and from the last 20 seconds of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBsUDu8aucs), NeXt in general seems to be able to add/modify topology information. How far does the NeXt integration with ODL go? Would I need to write my own app (which could use NeXt) which would need to use the RESTCONF APIs to add information to the topology? Or should I maybe create a virtual topology of the real network using mininet? Any other ideas?

I understand that an sdn controller is probably not the right kind of tool for this task, but other alternatives (e.g. [Net2Plan](http://www.net2plan.com/index.php), Visio, [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/products/yed)) are basically local solutions, a bit too complicated or provide no standardized DSL for topologies. Besides that, the documentation covering ODL and NeXt integration is very limited - couldn't get a grasp of how that integration should work (I'll try harder).